# How to write Generators , list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When i think about any problem , thinking via list comprehension doesn't come naturally.

Whats the best way to think through this?

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, examples made the difference.  List comprehensions may not come naturally until you've used them to solve a problem or two that a `for loop` would not solve as elegantly.

Some thoughts (others may have better examples):

- Given a list of words, find the words of length 5.
- Given a list of numbers, return the subset of primes, multiplied by 2
- Given a list of fortune cookie sayings (or tweets), return a list of the sayings that are under 10 words long with 'in bed' added to the end of each.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I think through list comprehensions.

1) I need to output a list

2) I'm starting with a list/iterable.

3) I either need to perform an action on all the elements and/or choose specific elements from the original list.

That leads me to the following construction:

`output = [ mangle(x) for x in selector(input)]`

mangle() is some function that alters an element. For example I might use `x.lower()` to make an element lower case.

I always use `x` as the iterator. Just keeps everything consistent (and I never use it as an iterator in a `for` loop).

selector() is a function that outputs `True` or `False`. Usually this will be some sort of if statement. I've mostly used this a test for existence, especially if I'm `mangling` the output. For example, `x for x in input if input`.

List comprehensions can be really great. I think that they really improve readibility and are way more than a neat trick. But remember, they're nothing more than a for loop inline.

It might be easiest to try writing for loops and attempt to translate them into a list comprehension.

Comment: good, but the part about `selector(input)` being a function is a bit misleading in my opinion.

Comment: >3) I either need to perform an action on all the elements and/or choose specific elements from the original list. `output = [ mangle(x) for x in selector(input)]` < -> `output = [ mangle(x) for x in selector(input) if check(x)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting out with list comprehensions, this is how I got my head around it. First write your for loop as normal:

```
results = []

# get all keys that aren't test strings and add to results list
for a in blah.keys():
  if a not in ('test', 'foo'):
    results.append(a)
```

Now to create a list comprehension, leave the for loops and if statements in the same order and put them on the same line, put the 'final result' code at the start:

```
results = [ results.append(a) for a in blah.keys() if a not in ('test', 'foo') ]
```

We are nearly there! We don't need to manually append(a) as whatever we put in that part of the expression will automatically get appended to the list, so the final expression is:

```
 # get all keys that aren't test strings and add to results list
 results = [ a for a in blah.keys() if a not in ('test', 'foo') ]
```

HTH!

Comment: how about when i need to compare elemts from two or even more separate list .. It becomes kind of nested comprehension . It is then i am blown off . It takes hard time to think through , test on idle and then get it running. Is there elegant way of thinking so it just comes away .. i am sure there will be and way i think is making it look complicated ... whats your thoughts , ideas while using comprehensions .

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are the same concept as thinking about a for loop except they are on one line, and you can use them inline as an argument.

```
myFunc([s.strip() for s in mystrings])
```

Generator comprensions dont create the list right away in memory. They step through the values when you iterate over them and can be more efficient if you will stop looping over them early and dont need the entire result right away